# Wrapping AsyncRead `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I am trying to wrap `AsyncRead` in another `AsyncRead` (and do some data processing on it). However when trying to store the `Future` of `.read()` I get lifetime problem: `self has an anonymous lifetime '_ but it needs to satisfy a 'static lifetime requirement`.

Code:

```
pub struct AsyncReadWrap {
    input: Pin<Box<dyn AsyncRead + 'static>>,
    future: Option<Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = std::io::Result<usize>>>>>
}

impl AsyncReadWrap {
    pub fn new(input: impl AsyncRead + Unpin + 'static) -> AsyncReadWrap {
        AsyncReadWrap {
            input: Box::pin(input),
            future: None
        }
    }
}

impl AsyncRead for AsyncReadWrap {
    fn poll_read(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>, buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        
        let mut buffer = [0u8; 2048];
        let future = self.input.as_mut().read(&mut buffer);
        self.future = Some(Box::pin(future));
       
        Poll::Pending
    }
}
```

I am new to async and it's weird that there isn't some simple way to `await` in `poll` functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `await` from a `poll` function, because `await` may call `poll` muliple times and yield control back to the executor in between. A single `poll` call may only yield *once*, and will only get resumed through another `poll` invocation. Polling and futures is the building block of `async`/`await` - you cannot use the higher level abstraction when working with the lower level implementation.

The problem with your current code is that your struct is *self-referential*. `input.read()` returns a future the may borrow from `input`:

```rust
// `Read` borrows from `self` and `buf`
fn read<'a>(&'a mut self, buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> Read<'a, Self>
```

You cannot store the returned future in your struct because [storing a value and a reference to that value in the same struct is problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct).

To create an `AsyncRead` wrapper, you can call `poll_read` on the inner `AsyncRead`. When `poll_read` returns `Ready`, the buffer will be filled with the read value, and you can perform data processing on it:

```rust
impl AsyncRead for AsyncReadWrap {
    fn poll_read(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>, mut buf: &mut ReadBuf<'_>) -> Poll<std::io::Result<()>> {
        match self.input.as_mut().poll_read(cx, &mut buf) {
            Poll::Ready(res) => {
                // do stuff with `buf`
                Poll::Ready(res)
            },
            Poll::Pending => Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

Performing more `async` operations inside the `poll_read` function will become complex, as you will have to keep track of the multiple states your `AsyncRead` implementation will be in. `async`/`await` is an abstraction over lower level future state machines. If you don't necessarily *require* implementing  `AsyncRead`, you can avoid lower-level futures entirely and just make this an `async` method:

```rust
pub async fn read(mut input: impl AsyncRead + Unpin) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
    input.read(&mut buf).await;
    // ...
    buf.to_vec()
}
```

If you choose to go the lower-level route, here are some useful resources:

- [Async in depth](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/async)
- [Pin and suffering](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/pin-and-suffering)
- [Async/Await](https://os.phil-opp.com/async-await/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, helped me understand this. I already tried the `poll_read` before, however for some reason it didn't work reading multiple times. Probably bug in my code. Will try again if my stream workaround fails.

Comment: @MakaloneLOgman Futures can be hard to write manually and are easy to get the wrong as the flow can be unintutive. Also note that if you return `Poll::Pending` the executor will never poll you again unless you [tell it to wake you up](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Waker.html). I'll link some resources in the answer to help you get started with lower-level async if you choose to go that route.

Comment: Yes, am trying right now, anything will help.

Comment: It's interesting that 1 out of only 5 unique words in the useful resources is literally 'suffering' though the other two are 'Async' and 'Await'

Comment: @oliver Well, low level async Rust is hard, there is no question about that. It's just that `async`/`await` is still very new and many lower-level details are still being exposed to beginners.

Comment: I'm scared to open it :/